# Multi-Dimensional Array -- PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following occurring in a function I'm writing...

```
    $eq_1_array = array();
    $eq_1_array[] = $x_1;
    $eq_1_array[] = $y_1;
    $eq_1_array[] = $y_1_orig;
    $eq_1_array[] = $z_1;
    $eq_1_array[] = $z_1_orig;
    $eq_1_array[] = $op_1;

    $eq_2_array = array();
    $eq_2_array[] = $x_2;
    $eq_2_array[] = $y_2;
    $eq_2_array[] = $y_2_orig;
    $eq_2_array[] = $z_2;
    $eq_2_array[] = $z_2_orig;
    $eq_2_array[] = $op_2;

    $sol_array = array();
    $sol_array[] = $x_sol_val;
    $sol_array[] = $y_sol_val;

    $final_return_array[] = array();
    $final_return_array[] = $eq_1_array;
    $final_return_array[] = $eq_2_array;
    $final_return_array[] = $sol_array;

    return $final_return_array;
```

Basically, I should be getting 3 arrays from `$final_return_array`.  However, the first array (`$eq_1_array`) is always empty.

If I do...

```
echo '<hr><hr>';
print_r($eq_1_array);   
echo '<hr><hr>';
```

after $eq_1_array is populated, the proper data is there.

If I do...

```
echo '<hr><hr>';
print_r($final_return_array);   
echo '<hr><hr>';
```

after $final_return_array is populated, the `$eq_1_array` array is empty.

Can the first element of a multi-dimensional array not by an array itself or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array assignment is incorrect. You're creating your array and assigning an empty array to the first element here:

```
$final_return_array[] = array();
```

It should be:

```
$final_return_array = array();
```

Comment: * **forehead smack** *  Agreed.  Thanks for seeing that.